# Leaflet: Detect zoom attempt on minZoom & constant tile level on zoom

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm using my own tiles for a non-geographic application and am trying to implement an internal zoom logic which is supposed to be independent of the tile server but using Leaflet's zoom detection.

```
old layer, zoom level: 2 -> ZOOM IN, load another tile layer  -> new layer, zoom level: 2
new layer, zoom level: 2 <- ZOOM OUT, load another tile layer <- old layer, zoom level: 2
```

It is possible to do this with manually removing the old layer setting `map.setZoom(oldZoom)` on zoomend. However, in the process, zoom level would be temporarily changed to 1 and the old layer will be removed only after the zoom animation.

```
map.on('zoom', testZoom);  

function testZoom() {
         if(newZoom == 1 && prevZoom == 2) {
            map.setZoom(2);
            map.removeLayer(activeTileLayer);
            map.addLayer(newLayer);
          }
}
```

An approach might be to *detect* when the user tries zooming at minZoom but I haven't found out how this could be possible.

Comment: Have you tried using the [tileLayer's `min`/`maxZoom` options](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#tilelayer-minzoom) at all?

Comment: @IvanSanchez Sure I have - but probably I haven't formulated my question well. What I want to achieve: If the user zooms at minZoom, I'd like to keep my zoom level but load tiles from _another_ tile server, i. e. increasing detail without increasing number of tiles. For this, I'd need to know when the user tries to zoom beyond minZoom/maxZoom.

Comment: If I understand correctly, at zoom level 2 you would like to DISRUPT the zoom experience so that a user zoom change request would NOT result in actual zoom change, but only in tile layer change?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'd like to use zoom controls to change the level of detail while keeping coordinates constant. For example, I could start with a map displaying topographic features only. On zoom in, the visible area should remain the same but the tile layer is supposed to change so that country borders become visible.